# Twig include with noscript tag rendered as a string and not code

Tags: templating

So I have an include file.

```
<noscript>
  <img
    src="{{ srcImage }}"
    alt="{{ alt }}"
  />
</noscript>
```

I am including like standard:

```
{% include '_includes/partials/image-noscript' %
```

but for some reason it is generating the code like so…

```
<noscript>
  &lt;img
    src="http://plowmancraven-v4.loc/imager/uploads/images/general/3172/PC-Enviro-Generic-London-shutterstock_370946690_3488bcae28a5a46889970c4f238b0c7c.jpg"
    alt="PC Enviro Generic London"
  /&gt;
</noscript>
```

Edit: Here are some of the things I have tried but nothing has solved this issue yet.

```
{%- include '_includes/partials/image-noscript' -%}
{% autoescape false %}{% include '_includes/partials/image-noscript' %}{% endautoescape %}
```

inside the included file:

```
<noscript><img src="{{ srcImage }}" alt="{{ alt }}" /></noscript>

{% spaceless %}<noscript><img src="{{ srcImage }}" alt="{{ alt }}" /></noscript>{% endspaceless %}

{% autoescape false %}
<noscript>
  <img
    src="{{ srcImage }}"
    alt="{{ alt }}"
  />
</noscript>
{% endautoescape %}

{% autoescape false %}<noscript>{% endautoescape %}
{% autoescape false %}
  <img
    src="{{ srcImage }}"
    alt="{{ alt }}"
  />
{% endautoescape %}
{% autoescape false %}</noscript>{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's escaping the text in the default (html) context, which should not be happening for a template you `include`

I suspect this is due to a larger issue, as templates that are included should not be escaped in this manner.

You can change the escaping strategy using block tags around the code, though:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

cf: [autoescape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't resolved the issue. I have updated my original question with the variations I have tried. Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If that doesn't work, something else is deeply wrong here.